# Issue Outputting Most Experienced Value

Tags: mysql, sql

Brand new to SQL.

I am trying to output the most used application by user for 2018.  Version: MySQL v5.7

Relations:

- user(UID: INT PRIMARY KEY, UNAME VARCHAR(100), LOCATION VARCHAR(100))
- application (AID: INT PRIMARY KEY, DID: INT NOT NULL, AppName VARCHAR(100), versionDate DATE)
- usageHistory(AID: INT NOT NULL, UID: INT NOT NULL, usageDate DATE NOT NULL)

My current attempt is throwing an `Invalid Use of Group Function` exception

```
SELECT user.UID, application.AID
FROM user
INNER JOIN usageHistory ON usageHistory.UID = user.UID
INNER JOIN application ON application.AID = usageHistory.AID
WHERE YEAR(usageHistory.usageDate) = 2018
GROUP BY user.UID
HAVING MAX(COUNT(usageHistory.AID))
```

I want to display User's Name | Most used application for 2018.
Example:

- Steve Smith | Facebook
- Jane Smith  | Twitter

(Pipes are purely for visualization)

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL 8+, you can use `ROW_NUMBER()`:

```
SELECT UID, AID
FROM (SELECT uh.UID, uh.AID,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY uh.UID ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) as seqnum
      FROM usageHistory uh
      WHERE uh.usageDate >= '2018-01-01' AND uh.usageDate < '2019-01-01'
      GROUP BY u.UID, a.AID
     ) ua
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

Notes:

- There is no need to join in `users` or `applications`.  The ids you want are in `usageHistory`.
- Try to use direct date comparisons.  This makes it easier for the query to be optimized.
- Table aliases make the query easier to write and to read.

Comment: how can I access the name of the application without joining applications?  I only know the application ID from the usageHistory not the name

Comment: @StormsEdge . . . For that, you would need to join to applications.  However, your question only includes the application id.

Comment: that is a typo I will correct it.  I would like to display the user's name not the ID.  My mistake.